# Viewing Core Data within an App

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, core-data

I was thinking of writing some UIViewControllers to display the data in my Core Data stores while developing and testing an app.

I was thinking of something like this: A view controller that allows the user to select parameters to be passed into a fetch request, then a table view controller to list the fetch results, and finally a view controller to display the data in a particular entry from the fetch results.

Does anyone know of some open source code already similar to this, or a different approach I should take for monitoring my data?

NOTE: To clarify, I'm talking about a generic solution that could be put into any app using CoreData with minimal configuration.

Comment: There's plenty of sample code out there to do this sort of thing --  get searching, and check out Apple's own samples. You are unlikely to find something that does exactly what you want, so accept you might have to customize and/or merge things that you find. Your general approach sounds ok, but your question is too vague to say much more.

Comment: I don't really need sample code - I already know how to write what I want. I'm just wondering if it has already been written. I would expect that other people would want to view their Core Data stores in-app while testing, so I was expecting to find a common solution. But maybe other people test differently?

Comment: Richard, been trying to reach you about BibleFox, my email addy is in my profile, can you send me a message so I can ask a few questions? Sorry about the tacky way of trying to reach you, but had no other ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but there is a new app in the mac app store which allows you to view and manipulate Core Data Stores. While it doesn't integrate in with your own app (and its not the cheapest software out there) you might find it helpful. I stumbled across it a few moments ago and thought of your question here.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/core-data-editor/id403025957?mt=12